# Spring 3.0 with Hibernate 3.2 MVC example with annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I want to integrate spring with hibernate using MVC with annotation.

If any one provide me simple example then its very help full for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Spring 4.x is out and that's what you want to use. Here is a link to the [Spring.io Site Guides](http://spring.io/guides) so that you can take a look at the available examples they have provided, simple, but enough to get you started. Specific to what you're asking, this is the link to [Accessing Data With JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) which is a wrapper for Hibernate using the annotations that you're asking about.